# How is data augmentation implemented in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Based on the [Tensorflow tutorial for ConvNet](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#convolutional-neural-networks), some points are not readily apparent to me:

- are the images being distorted actually **added** to the pool of original images?
- or are the distorted images used **instead** of the originals?
- how many distorted images are being produced? (i.e. what augmentation factor was defined?)

The flow of functions for the tutorial seems to be as follows:

**cifar_10_train.py**

```
def train
    """Train CIFAR-10 for a number of steps."""
    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        [...]
        # Get images and labels for CIFAR-10.
        images, labels = cifar10.distorted_inputs()
        [...]
```

**cifar10.py**

```
def distorted_inputs():
    """Construct distorted input for CIFAR training using the Reader ops.

    Returns:
      images: Images. 4D tensor of [batch_size, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3] size.
      labels: Labels. 1D tensor of [batch_size] size.

    Raises:
      ValueError: If no data_dir
    """
    if not FLAGS.data_dir:
        raise ValueError('Please supply a data_dir')
    data_dir = os.path.join(FLAGS.data_dir, 'cifar-10-batches-bin')
    return cifar10_input.distorted_inputs(data_dir=data_dir,
                                          batch_size=FLAGS.batch_size)
```

and finally **cifar10_input.py**

```
def distorted_inputs(data_dir, batch_size):
    """Construct distorted input for CIFAR training using the Reader ops.

    Args:
    data_dir: Path to the CIFAR-10 data directory.
    batch_size: Number of images per batch.

    Returns:
    images: Images. 4D tensor of [batch_size, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3] size.
    labels: Labels. 1D tensor of [batch_size] size.
    """
    filenames = [os.path.join(data_dir, 'data_batch_%d.bin' % i) for i in xrange(1, 6)]
    for f in filenames:
        if not tf.gfile.Exists(f):
            raise ValueError('Failed to find file: ' + f)

    # Create a queue that produces the filenames to read.
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames)

    # Read examples from files in the filename queue.
    read_input = read_cifar10(filename_queue)
    reshaped_image = tf.cast(read_input.uint8image, tf.float32)

    height = IMAGE_SIZE
    width = IMAGE_SIZE

    # Image processing for training the network. Note the many random
    # distortions applied to the image.

    # Randomly crop a [height, width] section of the image.
    distorted_image = tf.random_crop(reshaped_image, [height, width, 3])

    # Randomly flip the image horizontally.
    distorted_image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(distorted_image)

    # Because these operations are not commutative, consider randomizing
    # the order their operation.
    distorted_image = tf.image.random_brightness(distorted_image, max_delta=63)
    distorted_image = tf.image.random_contrast(distorted_image, lower=0.2, upper=1.8)

    # Subtract off the mean and divide by the variance of the pixels.
    float_image = tf.image.per_image_whitening(distorted_image)

    # Ensure that the random shuffling has good mixing properties.
    min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue = 0.4
    min_queue_examples = int(NUM_EXAMPLES_PER_EPOCH_FOR_TRAIN *
                             min_fraction_of_examples_in_queue)
    print('Filling queue with %d CIFAR images before starting to train.'
          'This will take a few minutes.' % min_queue_examples)

    # Generate a batch of images and labels by building up a queue of examples.
    return _generate_image_and_label_batch(float_image, read_input.label,
                                           min_queue_examples, batch_size,
                                           shuffle=True)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> are the images being distorted actually added to the pool of original images?

It depends on the definition of the pool. In tensorflow, you have `ops` which are basic objects in your network graph. here, data production is an op itself. Thus you do not have a finite set of training samples, instead you have **a potentialy infinite** set of samples **generated** from the training set.

> or are the distorted images used instead of the originals?

As you can see from the source you included - sample is taken from the training batch, then it is randomly transformed, thus there is very small probability of using unaltered image (especially that cropping is used, which always modifies).

> how many distorted images are being produced? (i.e. what augmentation factor was defined?)

There is no such thing, this is never ending process. Think about this in terms of random access to possibly infinite source of data, as this is what is efficiently happening here. Every single batch can be different from the previous one.

Comment: thanks for the insights @lejlot -- I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around this. Question: do you mean to say that by doing distortions we can go back to the training pool, hypothetically take the same batch of images but because of random distortions those cases will never be exactly the same, therefore they act as "new" cases? If this is correct, then that is how one could request 100k or more iterations from a finite dataset with less fear of overfitting?

Comment: pretty much yes. You get the same "raw" data, but before it gets passed to network it gets disorted in randomized way, thus the network never actually sees two samples twice

Comment: @lejlot, so each time we start training, the net will be basically trained on a different train set of images, cause each time train set will be "augmented" differently, right?

Comment: @Konrad to some extent yes, with enough "richness" of the transformations no 2 runs will be identical in terms of images produced.